# NoReverseMatch at /cart

Tags: python, django

**[I face this error even when i add forward slash / to the cart url its give no page found 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMdKz.png)**

No Reverse Match i think it because url routing it worked with me just for a few second without / for cart url and then it give me this error .

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
url(r'^cart', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

> this is the view code

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
cart = Cart(request)
product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    cart.add(product=product,
         quantity=cd['quantity'],
         update_quantity=cd['update'])
return redirect('cart:cart_detail')



def cart_remove(request, product_id):
cart = Cart(request)
product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
cart.remove(product)
return redirect('cart:cart_detail')

def cart_detail(request):
cart = Cart(request)
for item in cart:
    item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(
    initial={'quantity': item['quantity'],
    'update': True})
return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

> cart app urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views



urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
url(r'^add/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$',views.cart_add,name='cart_add'),
url(r'^remove/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$',views.cart_remove,name='cart_remove'),
]
```

Comment: did you tried the url `/cart/`?

Comment: Yes I tried it , it gives the same error

Comment: You should post the actual error, rather than a picture of it. Since that error shows that it is happening in the detail template, you should also post that template.

Comment: i am not able to edit the question

Comment: The error appear when i delete an item from the website or adding new items

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.urls import reverse

return redirect(reverse('cart:cart_detail'))
```